# How to ignore punctuation and symbols with bloodhound/typeahead

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have typeahead with bloodhound set up to pull from a list of schools, however it gets mixed up with cases like.

```
A.B. Meadows
```

when someone types:

```
AB
```

The docs say bloodhound has a tokenizer function and the examples shown lead me to believe it would be able to handle this. Any Ideas? Full code posted below.

```
var schools = ['A.B. Meadows','F.D. Creekfield'];
// constructs the suggestion engine
  var schoolSuggest = new Bloodhound({
    limit: 10,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: $.map(schools, function(school) { return { value: school }; })
  });

  // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
  schoolSuggest.initialize();

  $('.schoolward').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'wards',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: schoolSuggest.ttAdapter()
  });
```

Comment: will you use `local` even on your actual app ? If so then you can use custom stringmatcher

Comment: Most likely yes, I was looking into doing that with some simple regex but I got caught with how to tell the library to highlight the right text since Im returning a different substring than that of found in the display text.

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is local, a substring matcher with regex like `str.replace(/\./g,'');` should help. Below is the substring matcher.

```
var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substrRegex;
        matches = [];
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
            str2 = str.replace(/\./g,''); // this will remove period from being considered in search
            if (substrRegex.test(str2)) {
                matches.push({
                    value: str
                });
            }
        });
        cb(matches);
    };
};
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/12/)**